# Does a whole "compose" its parts?

Tags: word-usage

I just wrote a sentence like this and I'm wondering I've used the word *compose* correctly.

> In order to find the length of the train, you'll need to measure the individual cars it *composes*.

Is this correct, or would it be better phrased as "... of which it's composed"? Should I use another word, like *comprise*?

Comment: In some contexts I might say something like *"To establish the weight of this box of frogs, we could weigh the empty box, and the individual frogs **therein**"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. *Comprises* is right.

*Compose* indicates joining things together. "The cars compose the train; the train is composed of cars."

*Comprise* indicates splitting a composite (see what I did there?). "The train comprises its cars."

Comment: But equally (and more commonly in my experience) *the cars comprise the train*.

Comment: @TimLymington, also see wiktionary's [usage note](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comprise#Usage_notes) for *comprise*: "The most recent usages, compose and constitute, whereby the passive form effectively means “the members comprise the team”, are usually informal and often considered incorrect. By classical definition, a team comprises its members, whereas the members compose the team. It is not proper to use comprise in place of compose. ... These usages are, however, quite common, with the "compose" variation being more common than the "constitute" one."

Comment: @jwpat7: fair enough, *mea culpa*.

Answer (score 5):

Why use a relative clause? No verb is needed here; the cars aren't **doing** anything, after all.

Try either

> In order to find the length of the train, you need to measure the individual cars in it.

or

> In order to find the length of the train, you need to measure its individual cars.

(The contracted *will* is also unnecessary in context, so I deleted it too.)

Simpler is clearer.

Comment: I'm actually trying to emphasize the fact that a "train" comprises "cars." (The real sentence isn't about trains and cars.)

Comment: Simpler is still clearer. If you want to emphasize something, go right ahead and say it. Spend an extra sentence. They don't cost much, and they're easier to follow than fancy implications.

Answer (score 1):

The train does not compose its parts.

You could say it as:

> In order to find the length of the train, you'll need to measure the individual cars that it is composed of.